# Is there a way to recover a ggplot2 image from a Plotly image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerpoint, plotly

I have some code that generates a plotly image in R. Previously I included this plot in a presentation using Rstudio/ioslides. The people I am collaborating with want a version in powerpoint. I am trying to use the ReporterRs package in order to create an re-producible shell powerpoint presentation with all of my plots.  However ReporterRs only accepts lattice, ggplot2, and base images. Since there is a way to convert ggplot2 objects to plotly images I was hoping there was a way to go backwards. However I am stuck. I have been unable to "downgrade" my plotly plots to ggplot2. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

(I know I can just copy and paste them over but I would like to develop a workflow where I can create easily reproducible and replaceable plots so that I don't have to do very much work if I change the data)

Comment: I don't think so; plotly has a completely different back end. If you give the plotly code people might help you here with retrofitting it to ggplot ...

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. I can figure out how to re-do the plots using ggplot. The syntax is not that different. I was more hoping to avoid the work and improve my workflow. When I look at data I like the interactivity of plotly plots. However when I write up results or present them I really only need static versions. Maybe I'll have to start writing everything in ggplot2 and then using the ggploty function so I don't run into this problem again.